How to get all cached keys with certain prefix from the Cache in Laravel?
Is there a way in newer laravel versions to cache many things with a certain prefix and then get all by doing Cache::get('prefix_*) or something ?
I'm trying to cache the Online Users for like 5 minutes and I want the cache to expire for each user individually, unless the expiration is updated for it by using a middleware.
But the problem I have run into is that I can't retrieve all users if I store them as individual Keys:
 Cache::put('online_users_'.auth()->id(), auth()->user(), now()->addMinutes(5));

And I would like to get them by using something like :
Cache::get('online_users_'); or Cache::get('online_users_*');

I could try using tags for this problem , but as they are not even explained in the docs after laravel 10 , I was wondering if there is another way around this , that would allow for the individual keys to expire in their own and be individually stored.
Thanks.

I manage to get this working with the File driver!
By storing everyting inside of one key active_users and not using the ttl field of the put() method itself. But by keeping track of an expires_at field of my own inside the array.
Inside the middleware class I do something like this:
    $activeForMinutes = 5;
    $sessionId = session()->getId();
    $cachedActiveUsers = Cache::get('active_users') ?? [];

    // Remove expired sessions.
    foreach ($cachedActiveUsers as $key => $cachedActiveUser) {
        if (!$cachedActiveUser['expires_at']->isFuture()) {
            unset($cachedActiveUsers[$key]);
        }
    }

    $userData = [
        'session'    => $sessionId,
        'name'       => $this->getUserName(),
         // etc..
    ];

    // Add new data.
    $cachedActiveUsers[$sessionId] = $userData;
    Cache::put('active_users', $cachedActiveUsers);

And in the controller I can simply do this:
$activeUsers = Cache::get('active_users');

Hope this helps!

Since your idea is to put all "online users" in the same cache, you can do it like this:
Cache::put('online_users', [auth()->id() => auth()->user()], now()->addMinutes(5));

This essentially creates a key:value array inside your online_users cache.
Now, when you try to get the records from the cache:
Cache::get('online_users');

You would get data like this:
[
    1 => UserObject2,
    2 => UserObject1
]

where 1 or 2 will be your auth users ID, and UserObject1 or UserObject2 will be an object that gets returned by auth()->user().
You can then even get a specific user object from cache, like this:
Cache::get('online_users')[auth()->id];


I tried it like this tbh ,but If I'm not mistaken, this will cache the whole array and will not allow for each individual user to expire at a different time , since I will use a middleware to update the expiry time if the user is interacting with the website , 1 user might expire in 5 mins 1 user might be running out of time.Or?

Ah! Makes sense, I just realized that. Sorry, I will try to think of a new solution, and update the answer

I would appreciate a solution for the file driver ,but I managed the following using the REDIS driver ,to get all the keys and values based on the prefix online_user_*:
 public function index()
    {
        $cursor = '0';
        $onlineUsers= [];

        do {
            [$cursor, $keys] = Redis::scan($cursor, 'MATCH', 'online_user_*');

            foreach ($keys as $key) {
                $onlineUsers[$key] = Redis::get($key);
            }
        } while ($cursor !== '0');

        return view('view.name', [
           
            'onlineUsers' => $onlineUsers,
        ]);
    }

I also had to remove the prefix from database.php
 // 'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_') . '_database_'),

